# What's the best method to use a configuration file?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

.properties?
.xml?

What is the best method to have a configuration in a website?
In my case I need to have some variables, for example

server_home = "http://site.com"

site_name = "website's name"

default_language = "en"

images_folder = "/var/images/..."
...

Spring supports something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a ".properties" file, along side with Spring's `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`. Check out the javadoc http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html